# Set of symmetric matrices is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the following set is closed. 
$$ S_n = \{ A \;\epsilon \; \mathbb R^{n^2} | \text{A is symmetric} \} \,\subset\, \mathbb R ^{n^2}$$

We are given a hint to use this theorem: Let f be a function from $\mathbb R^n \, to \,\mathbb R^m$ Then, f conts $\iff f^{-1}(F) $ is closed for each closed set F in $\mathbb R^m$.

Not sure where to even begin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the following approach: $S_n$ is closed $\iff$ if a sequence $A^{(k)}$ in $S_n$ converges to $A$, then $A$ is in $S_n$. But assume that this does not happen. Then there exists a sequence $A^{(k)} \to A$ such as $A$ is not symmetric. So $a_{ij} \neq a_{ji}$ for some $i,j$. But, since $a^{(k)}_{ij} \to a_{ij}, a^{(k)}_{ji} \to a_{ji}$, you can then find $k_0$ large enough such as $k >= k_0$, $a^{(k)}_{ij} \neq a^{(k)}_{ji}$. Hence $A^{(k)}$ would not be symmetric, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

"Symmetric" means $A=A^T$. Or in other words $A-A^T = 0_{n\times n} $. Now think of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ as being the set of matrices. What function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ can you design that would make the set of symmetric matrices be $f^{-1} (\{ 0_{n\times n} \})$, i.e., the preimage of a closed set?