# Prove the set of symmetric matrices are not compact.

Tags: general-topology, matrices

> Prove that the set of symmetric matrices under $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is not compact for $n \ge 1$.

Let $S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be the subspace of symmetric matrices in $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Using the Heine-Borel Theorem, we need to show that either $S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is not closed or $S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is unbounded (using the Euclidean Norm).

I am under the impression that $S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is closed ([Set of symmetric matrices is closed [duplicate]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972544/set-of-symmetric-matrices-is-closed)
). That leaves us only to prove that $S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is unbounded. I understand that we need to show that $S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ cannot be contained in any open ball $B_\delta (x)$ in $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. However, I am quite lost on where to go from here, so any help is appreciated. If there is an easier way to go about proving this, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Find a sequence of symmetric matrices whose norm grows to infinity. To start: figure out what you should do to make a matrix have a large norm.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I would imagine this method would require large eigenvalues since $| \lambda | \le \|A\|$.

Comment: You are overthinking. Just take multiples of the identity.

Comment: the claim is also true for $n=1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_k:=kI_n$ for $k \in \mathbb N.$ Then we have $A_k \in S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $k$ and $||A_k|| \to \infty $ as $k \to \infty$, where $|| \cdot||$ is any norm on $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}).$